# Object.extend method

Tags: ruby, module, extend

I'm reading *the ruby programming language*. On page 251 of this book, there is this code:

```
countdown = Object.new # A plain old object
def countdown.each # The each iterator as a singleton method
    yield 3
    yield 2
    yield 1
end
countdown.extend(Enumerable) # Now the object has all Enumerable methods
print countdown.sort # Prints "[1, 2, 3]"
```

I cannot understand it. Where did the numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`) come from? `yield` method receives them. But those are not member variables, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually, if you look at the definition of [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend), you will see that it *"**adds** to obj the **instance** methods from each module given as a parameter"*. Internally it calls `Module.extend_object` and adds module's instance methods to a singleton class of Ruby object.
2. Yield method doesn't receive, it... yields :-) In order to make Enumerable work, `each` method should yield consecutive elements of your object - and that is exactly what it does. If you were to pass a block to this method like this:

   countdown.each { |x| puts x }

   You would see 3 2 1 as output. Sort just uses `each` to get full
   list of entries and then sorts them.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not member/instance variables. If I understand what you're asking, `Enumerable` is a module that defines lots of handy collection methods like `sort`. You add it to a class and it brings along all those methods. The only thing it requires *you* do is define a method called `each`. It should accept a block, then "yield" each member of the collection back to the block. `sort` (or whatever) will call `each` then do something with the members it is given back.

In this case the object is absurdly contrived, and the members are hard-coded into the `each` method. You could say it's an obfuscated form of:

```
`print [3, 2, 1].sort`
```